# Failed audit - did the system choose poorly?

Tags: discussion

I just failed this audit.
[image]

Other than possibly needing a *four-character* edit, it seemed okay to me.

**My question: Should I have failed this, or did the system choose poorly?**

Comment: That answer will of been removed as link only or low quality, IMO, it lacks any real details or solution and just says "there is nothing you can do" and that is also wrong as a good answer was given. It is technically an answer but it is also low quality. I agree, that is a tricky one but I think it should of been removed as low quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That answer could be reduced in characters to "This blows".

So, it doesn't propose a solution.  It doesn't point to a "We're working on it" thread.  Etc etc.

If it was refined to "This blows", would you still think it was an acceptable answer?

Comment: It's a bit more than that. It's "this blows because x and this link explains why".

Comment: That's fair.  I just don't see how it remains constructive.

Comment: But if even if it's the truth, it's still a low quality answer?

Comment: If it had linked here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1441861 and tried to reopen the bug report, I would have left it open, but as is I don't see it providing value - so low quality.